# Obtaining ASM of a program using C++

Tags: c++, decompiling

I was wondering if there is a simple way of using C++ to take a path of an executable and then fetch it's ASM? External library or command-line program solutions are accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't mind command-line utilities:

- Under Linux, one option is to use [`objdump -d`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump).
- Under Windows, one option is to use [DUMPBIN /DISASM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/disasm?view=vs-2017).